# DVD filenames contain quote marks; can't copy to Windows machine

Tags: windows, command-line, dvd

I need to copy some QuickTime videos from a DVD, but the filenames contain quotation marks so Windows prevents me from copying or moving them to my PC.

Does anyone know what can I do?

I am running Windows 7 Professional.

Answer (score 3):

Windows will not allow a filename containing quotation marks.

You can copy the files one at a time using wildcard characters, and giving a different name without quotes for the destination.

```
copy "f:?Behavioral Center? English.mov" "c:\video\Behavioral Center English.mov"
```

Comment: what do I need to put , 1st my file name is called "Behavioral Center" Englsih.mov

Comment: @TonyR, I've updated the example. Because your filename has spaces in it, you need to put quotes around the whole thing.

Answer (score 2):

try using `dir /X` to access the 8.3-style name. According to ( http://support.microsoft.com/kb/142982 ) the first step in windows making these names is to strip invalid characters.

Once you have access to the 8.3 name, rename it using valid characters.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried opening a command prompt and using "dir" to see what the real file name is?  Then just copy that instance there:

```
copy f:\xxx.yyy  c:\zzz\
```

Comment: yes, thats the first thing I tried but did not work